# Speeding up Eigen operator() calls in conjunction with operator+=

Tags: c++, eigen

I am working on a code that emulates a matrix-vector product. In this code, we are explicitly calculating the vector `A x`, but we do not have access to the full matrix `A`, as `dim` is typically very large such that the full matrix `A` cannot be stored in memory.

By doing some timings, we have established that the following loop takes about 4 seconds to complete. `string` is a an instance of a custom class, basically a wrapper around an `unsigned long`, and `matvec` is an `Eigen::VectorXd`.

```
// Off-diagonal contributions
for (size_t I = 0; I < dim; I++) {

    for (size_t p = 0; p < K; p++) {
        if (string.isOccupied(p)) {  // p in I
            for (size_t q = 0; q < p; q++) {
                if (!string.isOccupied(q)) {

                    string.annihilate(p);
                    string.create(q);

                    size_t J = string.address();

                    matvec(I) += value(p,q) * x(J);
                    matvec(J) += value(p,q) * x(I);

                    string.annihilate(q);
                    string.create(p);
                }
            } // q < p loop
        }
    }  // p loop

    string.nextPermutation();
}
```

In trying to determine the bottleneck of this loop, we tried a variety of things, such as optimizing the `annihilate` and `create` calls, but these have little effect. However, when we time the code without the `Eigen::VectorXd` value updating, i.e.

```
// Off-diagonal contributions
for (size_t I = 0; I < dim; I++) {

    for (size_t p = 0; p < K; p++) {
        if (string.isOccupied(p)) {  // p in I
            for (size_t q = 0; q < p; q++) {
                if (!string.isOccupied(q)) {

                    string.annihilate(p);
                    string.create(q);

                    size_t J = string.address();

                    string.annihilate(q);
                    string.create(p);
                }
            } // q < p loop
        }
    }  // p loop

    string.nextPermutation();
}
```

the loop now only takes 0.2 seconds. <strike>From this, we have deduced that the bottleneck is actually adding the right values to the resulting vector.</strike> *see the edit*

Is there a faster way to do the `matvec(I) += value(p,q) * x(J)` calls, using the C++ Eigen library?

---

**EDIT**: I have done some better timings, inspired by @PeterT and @chtz's comments, and I find that the `+=` statements take about **30%** of all the time spent in the `for` loop, whereas the other parts all take about an equally proportioned size of the remaining time.

So, the question remains: how can the `matvec(I) += value(p,q) * x(J)` and `matvec(J) += value(p,q) * x(I)` be sped up?

Comment: I don't think your assertion necessarily holds that the singular bottleneck is the `matvec(I) += value(p,q) * x(J)` call. You could be preventing SIMD optimizations with your `if`s, can you somehow express them as unconditional multiplications or something similar

Comment: Did you read http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_do_I_get_good_performance.3F ?  I have found drastic improvement by defining `NDEBUG`

Comment: do you use compiler optimizations? My first guess is that if you dont add the values to the resulting vector then also all the computations leading to that values are optimized away which would explain that drastic difference you observe

Comment: @PeterT I am not familiar with SIMD optimizations. I can tell you that `string` can be looked at as an `unsigned long`, of which the first (from right to left) `K` bits are of importance. The first `for` checks if the `p`-th bit is toggled, the second `for` checks if the `q`-th bit isn't. I currently have no idea how to express that as something unconditional.

Comment: @Matt I have indeed read it. `#define EIGEN_NDEBUG` had no effect in this case, and I got a `malloc` error when using `-march=native`, which I haven't debugged (yet).

Comment: @user463035818 I have, per your suggestion, compiled without any compiler optimizations. Using a smaller example, I find 8500 microseconds for the first loop, and 2400 microseconds for the second loop. The difference is less drastic, but does seem to suggest that the `operator()` calls are taking a significant portion of the time.

Comment: Why guess when you can measure. Have you tried to use a proper profiler to see which instructions actually take how much time and to see how much you're potentially memory speed bound?

Comment: Compiling Eigen without optimization is generally a bad idea. I guess @user463035818 wanted to point out that parts of your second version might not have any side-effects and get optimized away.

Comment: what I meant with the rewriting without conditionals was for example `if (!string.isOccupied(q)) { a += b;}` which can be rewritten as `a+= b*(!string.isOccupied(q))` .

Comment: What times do you get if you do something non-trivial, like accumulating `(I+p)*(J+q)` inside your inner loop (and returning or outputting the result at the end)?

Comment: @PeterT I believe that is impossible in my case, as the `string` actually gets changed during the `annihilate` and `create` calls.

Comment: @chtz that was a good suggestion. Using your non-trivial example, the timings were similar to the first code block. I have updated my question with more accurate timings.

Comment: I don't know what timings you actually expect -- e.g., it is still unclear to me what actually happens inside your `string` object. You should provide a proper [mcve]